# Cache calls to simple service in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to cache some services that bring data to be filled on comboboxes. This is one:

```
getDisciplinas(req?: any): Observable<ComboArrayResponseType> {
  const options = createRequestOption(req);
  return this.http.get<ICombo[]>(this.disciplinaUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
}
```

what I'm trying to do is:

```
cachedDisciplina = new Map < string, Observable<any>>();

getDisciplinas(req?: any): Observable<ComboArrayResponseType> | undefined {
  if (!this.cachedDisciplina.get(req)) {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    const r =  this.http.get<ICombo[]>(this.disciplinaUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map((response: Response) => response.json()),
      publishReplay(1, 3000),
      refCount(),
      take(1));
    this.cachedDisciplina.set(req, r)
  }
  return this.cachedDisciplina.get(req);
}
```

The current error I'm getting is matching the types:

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Response, Promise<any>>' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<ICombo[]>, Promise<any>>'.
Type 'HttpResponse<ICombo[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response':
redirected, trailer, bodyUsed, arrayBuffer, and 4 more.
```

But I tried many things with different errors. I need my request to be cached including the parameter so I tried this apprach with the map, but I can't make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

u try to set Observable as value for map
u need to

```
r.subscribe(response => this.cachedDisciplina.set(req, response)); // don't forgot unsubscribe!
```

or

```
this.cachedDisciplina.set(req, await r.toPromise())
```

and **Map key must be string**, so try to **stringify your req**